# Passing values from Fragments and displaying text if correct answers

Tags: java, android

I have two `Fragments` with `rbs`. When first `rb` in `Fragment1` is selected and second `rb` in `Fragment2` is selected, how to display message in `Fragment3` "Good answers"?

Note that I don't want to use any `checkButton` in `Fragment3` but have "Good answers" displayed automatically right after all correct `rbs` are checked by user.

Here is the code for `rb1` in `Fragment1` and accordingly there is the same for `rb2`in `Fragment2`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    RadioGroup rg1  = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                checked[0] = true;
                answer[0] = true;
            } else {
                checked[0] = true;
                answer[0] = false;
            }
        }
    });
    return view;

}
```

Please use simple programming language :) Thanks

Comment: check here :https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
if you don't get please fill free to ask.

Comment: Thank you Jaydeep. I'd just like to have some code example based on my case. It's just easier for me to understand it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RxAndroid like EventBus to do your best. You have this example to learn a bit about RxAndroid.

http://www.oscargarrucho.com/blog/2016/implementando-un-eventbus-con-rxandroid/
You can download the project example in the post.

(in Spanish).

Comment: Thank you Oskarko

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer has solved your problem you should mark it as the good answer for the people who have the same question in the future as you had today ;)

Comment: No it haven't. Looking at this code I just can't understand how to implement it to my `Fragments`. And I don't know Spanish :) But thanks for it anyway.